# How to completely remove EN keyboard layout on MacOS Sonoma?

Tags: keyboard

I've installed the [Programmer Dvorak keyboard layout](https://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/macosx.html) and don't need the default one but I don't know how to remove it because in settings the "-" is disabled for EN layout. In a previous version of macOS, I did the next thing

```
    for file in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist; do
    for key in AppleCurrentKeyboardLayoutInputSourceID; do
        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "delete :${key}" ${file}
        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :${key} string 'com.apple.keyboardlayout.Programmer Dvorak'" ${file}
    done
    for key in AppleDefaultAsciiInputSource AppleCurrentAsciiInputSource AppleCurrentInputSource AppleEnabledInputSources AppleInputSourceHistory AppleSelectedInputSources; do
        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "delete :${key}" ${file}
        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :${key} array" ${file}
        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :${key}:0 dict" ${file}
        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :${key}:0:InputSourceKind string 'Keyboard Layout'" ${file}
        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add ':${key}:0:KeyboardLayout ID' integer 6454" ${file}
        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add ':${key}:0:KeyboardLayout Name' string 'Programmer Dvorak'" ${file}
    done
done
```

But with the new OS version, it doesn't work.